# What is the difference between ix and element in the Lens library of Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

In Haskell's lens library, `ix` and `element` both take an Int an can be used e.g. to read or write a list element at some index, like this

```
ghci> [1..10] ^? ix 4
Just 5
ghci> [1..10] & ix 4 .~ 1
[1,2,3,4,1,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and similarly:

```
ghci> [1..10] ^? element 4
Just 5
ghci> [1..10] & element 4 .~ 1
[1,2,3,4,1,6,7,8,9,10]
```

What is the difference between `element` and `ix`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `ix` you can index not only by number, but by e.g. key in the Maps. The `element` index in `Traverse` order.

```
λ> let m = Map.fromList [("foo", 'f'), ("bar", 'b')]
λ> m ^? ix "foo"
Just 'f'

λ> m ^? element 0 -- Map is ordered container!
Just 'b'
```

The difference is even more obvious with e.g. `IntMap`

```
λ> let im = IntMap.fromList [(1, "one"), (2, "two")]
λ> im ^? ix 1
Just "one"
λ> im ^? element 1
Just "two"
```

Answer (score 4):

`element` is defined to work with types of the `Traversable` class, even class members which the lens library doesn't know about. As such it uses only `Traversable` functions to access the value, which have no concept of any index type specific to the type of value. As such, only `Int` indices are supported, giving elements in the usual traversal order.

`element` also gives an `IndexedTraversal`, giving some extra ways of handling indices.

`ix` is only defined for types the lens library knows about, but in return it can use different index types dependent on the type of the value.

For lists they give the same result.  But the difference can be seen e.g. for `Data.Map`:

```
Prelude Control.Lens Data.Map> singleton "a" 3 ^? element "a"

<interactive>:19:28:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the first argument of ‘element’, namely ‘"a"’
    In the second argument of ‘(^?)’, namely ‘element "a"’
    In the expression: singleton "a" 3 ^? element "a"

Prelude Control.Lens Data.Map> singleton "a" 3 ^? ix "a"
Just 3
Prelude Control.Lens Data.Map> singleton "a" 3 ^? element 0
Just 3
Prelude Control.Lens Data.Map> singleton "a" 3 ^? ix 0

<interactive>:22:23:
    Could not deduce (Num [Char]) arising from the literal ‘0’
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the inferred type of it :: Num a => Maybe a
      at <interactive>:22:1-23
    In the first argument of ‘ix’, namely ‘0’
    In the second argument of ‘(^?)’, namely ‘ix 0’
    In the expression: singleton "a" 3 ^? ix 0
```

As you can see, with `element` the map is given `Int` indices, while with `ix` it is given the key type as index, and trying to switch that around gives a type error.

Answer (score 3):

`element` works by walking an entire structure, counting the elements, and traversing the element with the target index. Therefore it always has time complexity O(n) in the size of the structure, and it only works  with `Int` indices.

In contrast, `ix` has its own class `Ixed`, and instances rely on the lookup/modify operations of the specific data structures. For example, `ix` for `Data.Sequence` is O(log n).

However, `ix` only works on specific data structures, while `elementOf` works with any `Traversal`, `Lens` or `Iso`, for example:

```
[0..10] ^? elementOf (reversed . each . filtered odd) 1
-- Just 7
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 for mentioning the complexity, I was actually worried about that. It makes total sense. So it seems we should use ix where possible.

Comment: Why does `element` need to walk the entire structure?

Comment: Because the type of `element` is `Traversable t => Int -> IndexedTraversal' Int (t a) a`, and there is no random element access method in `Traversable t`. If we only know this much about a type, the only way of accessing an element is to `traverse` and count elements until the target is reached.